TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter' AND 'play')
I am having errors when trying to use Azure maps control and animations in a TypeScript project.
I have this errror in browser's console when upon starting: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter').
I had understood that both control and animations had to be in the same 'atlas' namespace so I merged the namespace manually, planning to add exports when required:
import * as azmaps from 'azure-maps-control'
import * as azanimations from 'azure-maps-animations'

namespace atlas { 
    export const AuthenticationType = azmaps.AuthenticationType; 
    export const Map = azmaps.Map; 
    export const source = azmaps.source; 
    export const layer = azmaps.layer; 
    export const data = azmaps.data; 
    export const Shape = azmaps.Shape; 
    export const animations = azanimations.animations; 
}

Code works but on start, I get this : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter')
In the file: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-animations/blob/main/typings/index.d.ts
I saw this:
export abstract class PlayableAnimation extends azmaps.internal.EventEmitter<PlayableAnimationEvents> implements IPlayableAnimation

I noticed that azmaps is defined as :
import * as azmaps from 'azure-maps-control';

Web page still runs, it builds the anim object, that I defined as a global for now:
anim: any = atlas.animations.moveAlongRoute(routePoints, ...)

On Click, it tries to run the play() method but can't find it at runtime :
map.events.add('click', function () {
    anim.play();
});

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play').

I tried to cast anim as atlas.animations.PlayableAnimation; but TypeScript complained:  'atlas.animations.PlayableAnimation' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof atlas.animations.PlayableAnimation'.  I don't know what to do with this :(
Thanks for your help.

Sounds like something is a function and not a playable animation object. Perhaps try adding new before atlas.animations.moveAlongRoute.
As for EventEmitter, that is a base class used by Azure Maps layers. You should be able to see it under azmaps.internal.EventEmitter try adding the internals to your atlas namespace merge.

Thanks, var anim: atlas.animations.PlayableAnimation; worked when importing as type instead of const !   For EventEmitter though, I still have issues, I'll wrote another question with the full code where I tried to merge everything.
